# Undefined offset #####

Tags: php, undefined, offset

Code returns:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0  line 60
Notice: Undefined offset: 1  line 61
Notice: Undefined offset: 2  line 62
```

I don't know where is a mistake. I have no idea, so I need some help.

Part of code is below:

```
    private function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=','>','<','>=' ,'<=');


            $field      = $where[0]; //-----> LINE 60
            $operator   = $where[1]; //-----> LINE 61
            $value      = $where[2]; //-----> LINE 62

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;

                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're declaring an array like that? You can just use `$operators = ['=', '>', '<', '>=', '<='];` and what are you passing as `$where`? You don't need to strictly declare that it's an array either, though not sure on common practices there (I just ensure to never send a **not** array through to the function)

Comment: output of `var_dump($where);`?

Comment: @SebastianBroschyou gave me a hint. I got mistake in index.php 
$user = DB::getInstance()->insert('users', array(
  'username' => 'Dale',
  'password' => 'password',
  'salt' => 'salt'
 ));
I wrote 
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array(...

Tnx, man.

Comment: We would need to see how you are calling this function i.e. what is in the `$where` variable. We have to assume NOTHING